# link_to rails linking to published website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

Currently all my link_to tags in Ruby on Rails when run on localhost:3000 direct me to my live website whats up with that?

Currently my code is

```
%nav.col-lg-6.col-md-8.col-sm-10.col-xs-12.clearfix
  %ul
    %li
      =link_to 'Contact' , contact_path, :class => is_active?('contact')
    %li
      =link_to 'Projects', projects_path, :class => is_active?('index')
    %li
      =link_to 'Home', root_path, :class => is_active?('home')
```

https://github.com/Snowfiring/Mika

http://jsfiddle.net/kN6QS/

Comment: Did you put the url of your live website somewhere in your routes.rb?

Comment: No not at all I don't get how it could be doing this I'm really confused I'll add a link to the git

Comment: the generated HTML for these links is?

Comment: Fiddle added to show generated html

Comment: right at the top you set  <base href='http://www.mikakalathil.ca'>, all further links are relative to this

Answer (score 1):

You have this line in your application layout:

https://github.com/Snowfiring/Mika/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml#L10

This will set all URLs to be based off that base URL.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense thanks guess ill remove that for now is it even necessary? I mostly put it there for SEO

Comment: it's not necessary at all, and has nothing to do with SEO.

Comment: Ok thanks thats good to know theres a tun of garbage info out there regarding SEO